# GCC dependency generation for a different output directory

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, dependencies

I'm using GCC to generate a dependency file, but my build rules put the output into a subdirectory. Is there a way to tell GCC to put my subdirectory prefix in the dependency file it generates for me?

```
gcc $(INCLUDES) -E -MM $(CFLAGS) $(SRC) >>$(DEP)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer is in the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/cpp/Invocation.html): use the `-MT` flag.

> `-MT target`
>
> Change the target of the rule emitted by dependency generation. By default CPP takes the name of the main input file, deletes any directory components and any file suffix such as `.c`, and appends the platform's usual object suffix. The result is the target.
>
> An `-MT` option will set the target to be exactly the string you specify. If you want multiple targets, you can specify them as a single argument to `-MT`, or use multiple `-MT` options.
>
> For example, `-MT '$(objpfx)foo.o'` might give
>
> ```
> $(objpfx)foo.o: foo.c
> ```

Comment: `-MT` is not available for my gcc 2.9.5, guest should be available 3.x.x above

Comment: @checksum: ... wasn't [2.9.5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-2.95/) was released >14 years ago?

Comment: Yup, I found that out when maintaining a legacy code with out of date build platform. :| It is still using 2.9.1.57 (was call egcs instead of gcc) and the good thing is it has minimum dependency with 4 files only and less than 700k. :) The bad thing is it has no `-MT` support. :(

Answer (score 45):

I'm assuming you're using GNU Make and GCC.  First add a variable to hold your list of dependency files.  Assuming you already have one that lists all our sources:

```
SRCS = \
        main.c \
        foo.c \
        stuff/bar.c

DEPS = $(SRCS:.c=.d)
```

Then include the generated dependencies in the makefile:

```
include $(DEPS)
```

Then add this pattern rule:

```
# automatically generate dependency rules

%.d : %.c
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -MF"$@" -MG -MM -MP -MT"$@" -MT"$(<:.c=.o)" "$<"

# -MF  write the generated dependency rule to a file
# -MG  assume missing headers will be generated and don't stop with an error
# -MM  generate dependency rule for prerequisite, skipping system headers
# -MP  add phony target for each header to prevent errors when header is missing
# -MT  add a target to the generated dependency
```

"$@" is the target (the thing on the left side of the : ), "$<" is the prerequisite (the thing on the right side of the : ).  The expression "$(<:.c=.o)" replaces the .c extension with .o.

The trick here is to generate the rule with two targets by adding -MT twice; this makes both the .o file and the .d file depend on the source file and its headers; that way the dependency file gets automatically regenerated whenever any of the corresponding .c or .h files are changed.

The -MG and -MP options keep make from freaking out if a header file is missing.

Comment: For me, on gcc 4.1.2, gmake 3.8.1, if a header file does not exist the recipe '$(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -MF"$@" -MG -MM -MP -MT"$@" -MT"$(<:.c=.o)" "$<"' infinite loops. // Removing the -MP option stops the infinite loop.

Answer (score 14):

You may like this briefer version of [Don McCaughey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97338/gcc-dependency-generation-for-a-different-output-directory/2045668#2045668):

```
SRCS = \
    main.c \
    foo.c \
    stuff/bar.c
```

`DEPS = $(SRCS:.c=.d)`

Add `-include $(DEPS)` note the `-` prefix, which silences errors if the `.d` files don't yet exist.

There's no need for a separate pattern rule to generate the dependency files.  Simply add `-MD` or `-MMD` to your normal compilation line, and the `.d` files get generated at the same time your source files are compiled.  For example:

```
%.o: %.c
     gcc $(INCLUDE) -MMD -c $< -o $@

# -MD can be used to generate a dependency output file as a side-effect of the compilation process.
```

Comment: By the way, be sure to avoid placing the "include" above your first target.  It's logical to place it at the bottom of the Makefile, because that was always the traditional place to put dependencies, back when they had to be crafted by hand!

Answer (score 3):

Detailing on [DGentry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97338/gcc-dependency-generation-for-a-different-output-directory/97374#97374), this has worked well for me:

```
.depend: $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $(SOURCES) | sed 's|[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\.o|$(OBJDIR)/&|' > ./.depend
```

This also works in the case where there is only one dependency file that contains the dependency rules for all source files.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, just to make sure I've got the question right: I'm assuming you have `test.c` which includes `test.h`, and you want to generate `subdir/test.d` (while *not* generating `subdir/test.o`) where `subdir/test.d` contains

```
subdir/test.o: test.c test.h
```

rather than

```
test.o: test.c test.h
```

which is what you get right now. Is that right?

I was not able to come up with an easy way to do exactly what you're asking for. However, looking at *[Dependency Generation Improvements](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/news/dependencies.html)*, if you want to create the `.d` file while you generate the .o file, you can use:

```
gcc $(INCLUDES) -MMD $(CFLAGS) $(SRC) -o $(SUBDIR)/$(OBJ)
```

(Given `SRC=test.c`, `SUBDIR=subdir`, and `OBJ=test.o`.) This will create both subdir/test.o and subdir/test.d, where `subdir/test.d` contains the desired output as above.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an argument to GCC to do this, I don't know what it is. We end up piping the dependency output through [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) to rewrite all occurrences of `<blah>.o` as `${OBJDIR}/<blah>.o`.

Answer (score 0):

1. [GNU] make gets angry if you don't place the output in the current directory. You should really run make from the build directory, and use the VPATH make variable to locate the source code. If you lie to a compiler, sooner or later it will take its revenge.
2. If you insist on generating your objects and dependencies in some other directory, you need to use the `-o` argument, as [answered by Emile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97338/gcc-dependency-generation-for-a-different-output-directory/97710#97710).