# How can I make my Makefiles better?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, g++

I've trying to learn the "best practice" makefile's for a project.

Please review my Makefile file below and suggest changes to enhance it.

The dir layout:

```
root dir
---  Makefile
deps
---  deps
bin
---  binary
objs
---  all .o files
include
---  all .h files
src
---  all .c .cc files
```

The makefile:

```
#
# Generic makefile
#

all: tengine test2

#
# Include files for compiling, and libraries for linking.
#

INC=-I /usr/include -I /usr/local/include -I /usr/include/hiredis

LIB=-lhiredis

#
# Debug or not debug?
#

DEBUG=1

ifdef DEBUG
    CFLAGS=-Wall -Winline -pipe -g -DDEBUG #-pedantic -pg 
else
    CFLAGS=-Wall -Winline -pipe -O3 -march=native -funroll-all-loops \
           -finline-functions #-pedantic 
endif

#CXXFLAGS=$(CFLAGS)


# Rules for creating dependency files

deps/%.d: src/%.cc
    @echo Generating $@
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) -MM -MT '$(patsubst src/%,obj/%,%(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$<))' $< > $@

deps/%.d: src/%.c
    @echo Generating $@
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) -MM -MT '$(patsubst src/%,obj/%,%(patsubst %.c,%.o,$<))' $< > $@


# Rules for compilation
#
# C source with header and no c++ code

obj/%.o: src/%.c src/%.h deps/%.d
    @echo Compiling $@
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o $@ -c $<

# C++ source with header.

obj/%.o: src/%.cc src/%.h deps/%.d 
    @echo Compiling $@
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) -o $@ -c $<

# C source without header and no c++ code

obj/%.o: src/%.c deps/%.d
    @echo Compiling $@
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o $@ -c $<

# C++ source without header.

obj/%.o: src/%.cc deps/%.d 
    @echo Compiling $@
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) -o $@ -c $<

# ##############################################################
#
# TARGET: tengine
#
# ##############################################################

OBJS= obj/main.o obj/tengine.o 

tengine: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -pipe $(CXXFLAGS) -o bin/tengine $(OBJS) $(LIB)

# ##############################################################
#
# TARGET: test2
#
# ##############################################################

OBJS= obj/main.o obj/test2.o 

test2: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -pipe $(CXXFLAGS) -o bin/test2 $(OBJS) $(LIB)

# ##############################################################
#
# Cleanup
#
# ##############################################################

clean:
    rm -f *~ bin/* obj/* deps/* src/*~ gmon.out

help:

@echo ""
@echo "make     - builds tengine"
@echo "make test2   - builds test2"
@echo "make all     - builds tengine test2"
@echo "make clean   - deletes prior build"
```

Comment: do you really need that many section titles?

Comment: You probably need to change the `tengine` to `test2` in the `test2` section.  I'd remove a lot of the comments in the Makefile as they are  mostly noise. You should also use a macro for `g++` and for `-pipe` in the link lines.  Libraries should be listed after objects if your makefiles are to be robust. You also don't seem to set CXXFLAGS but you use it.

Comment: Thanks. I made those changes. I added the comments for the purposes of SO, I normally do not have them in my Makefile. CXXFLAGS was commented out in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect other people to use your Makefile, always include a `help` target that prints out a message detailing the various targets that are sensible to call from the command line, and the various environment vars which can be reasonably set to do various things...

Comment: I like it! Added that to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion for a revised makefile, tested slightly on a 7-year-old version of Linux (RHEL 5):

```
# Generic makefile

TARGETS=tengine test2

all: ${TARGETS}

help:
        @echo ""
        @echo "make         - builds ${TARGETS}"
        @echo "make tengine - builds tengine"
        @echo "make test2   - builds test2"
        @echo "make clean   - deletes prior build"
        @echo "make help    - prints this help"

# Switches:

INC=-I/usr/include/hiredis
LIB=-lhiredis
SUBDIRS=obj deps bin
LNK=gcc -g -Wl,--warn-common
DEBUG=1

ifdef DEBUG
        CFLAGS=-Wall -Winline -pipe -g -DDEBUG #-pedantic -pg 
else
        CFLAGS=-Wall -Winline -pipe -O3 -march=native -funroll-all-loops \
                   -finline-functions #-pedantic 
endif

#CXXFLAGS=$(CFLAGS)

# Generic rules:

obj/%.o: src/%.c
        @echo Compiling $@
        @mkdir -p $(SUBDIRS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -MMD -MF '$(patsubst src/%.c,deps/%.d,$<)' -o $@ -c $< 

obj/%.o: src/%.cc 
        @echo Compiling $@
        @mkdir -p $(SUBDIRS)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) -MMD -MF '$(patsubst src/%.c,deps/%.d,$<)' -o $@ -c $<

${TARGETS}: %:bin/%

# Specific target rules:

bin/tengine: obj/main.o obj/tengine.o
        $(LNK) $^ $(LIB) -o $@ 

bin/test2: obj/main.o obj/test2.o
        $(LNK) $^ $(LIB) -o $@ 

clean:
        rm -f *~ src/*~ gmon.out
        rm -fr $(SUBDIRS)

-include deps/*.d
```

Some notes:

- A key problem with the original was that the dependency were generated, but *not* used. This has been fixed using `-include deps/*.d` (at the end).
- Now that deps/*.d is used, the makefile doesn't need to have the `src/%.h` cases.
- The original was also putting garbage into these files: in `$(patsubst src/%,obj/%,%(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$<))` the third `%` should have been a `$`.
- In the revised version, the dependencies are generated at the same time as the object, using `-MMD`. This is quicker, shortens the makefile, and adds some DRY.
- Shortened `INC`: why bother including the standard system include directories? And in fact gcc will apparently ignore your `-I /usr/include -I /usr/local/include` anyway.
- Removed your *two* different definitions of `OBJS`. Not needed, and potentially confusing. Used `$^` instead.
- It is always a good idea for `make clean` to completely *undo* everything make does, so you are left with what you started. But the sub-directories obj/ and deps/ were being created, and never deleted. Also, bin/ was pre-supposed to exist.
- For the linking, added `$(LNK)`, with `LNK=gcc -g -Wl,--warn-common` (but you may not want the warnings). AFAIK, all the other usual `$(CFLAGS)` are ignored for links.
- Removed comments, which were (mostly) distracting.
- Repeated twice `make;make` now gives `make: Nothing to be done for ...`.

See also [gcc dependency generation for a different output directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/97338/318716).

Answer (score -1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) answers for examples about `Makefile`. Also run `make -p` to understand the builtin rules inside *GNU make*, so use `$(LINK.cc)` for e.g. your `bin/tengine` target.

For complex builds, consider upgrading to [GNU make 4.0](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/make-w32/2013-10/msg00021.html) and use its [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) ability.

You may want to generate automatically dependencies. Read [automatic prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html) and about [autodependencies](http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html); read also about [GCC preprocessor options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) like `-M` or `-MD` etc etc ....