# build makefile with different folders in application

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to creat a makefile for my project, but I really don't understand this devil thing.

When I was doing it in Java, with ant, it was much more simplier.

The structure of my program is: http://imageshack.com/a/img39/6592/jsxa.png

I read about creating makefiles but, when they answer a question similiar, they just put the done makefile and don't explain a lot about what they're doing.

So, what I need to do is create a makefile that stay in a folder named foo (foo/makefile) together with the src folder(foo/src/).
The makefile needs to create a folder named bin (foo/bin/) and put *.o files in there. Then build the program (DisqueRango.cpp contais the main function) and run it using 4 arguments: "-e couriers.csv -c menu.csv".

I'm not asking for the done makefile. What I need is an explanation about what I need to do it by myself.

Thank you indeed.

makefile of src/clients/

```
CC := g++

OBJ = *.cpp

all: prog

prog:
    $(CC) -c $(OBJ)
```

makefile of src/disquerango/ (contais main function)

```
CC := g++

BASEDIR := ..
MODULES := clients couriers products read requests
OBJS    := $(addsuffix /*.o, $(addprefix $(BASEDIR)/,$(MODULES)))

.PHONY: clean

all:
    $(CC) -o disquer DisqueRango.cpp $(OBJS)
```

and the makefile who call them all (same folder of src):

```
CC  := g++

BASEDIR := src
PROJN   := disquerango
MODULES := clients couriers products read requests disquerango
OBJS    := $(addprefix $(BASEDIR)/,$(MODULES))

all: compila run limpa

compila:
        for dir in $(OBJS); do (cd $$dir; ${MAKE} all); done

run: compila
    ./$(BASEDIR)/$(PROJN)/disquer -e entregadores.csv -c cardapio.csv

limpa:
    rm -f $(BASEDIR)/$(PROJN)/disquer
    for dir in $(OBJS); do (cd $$dir; rm -f *.o); done
```

Comment: Why do you have directories inside your project? What for? Do you intend to build part of your project as a reusable library? See e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108) & [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21423765/841108) answers...

Comment: I have directories cause the teacher want it. It's a project of graduation class.

Comment: Read [recursive make considered harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/).

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual?  It has pretty good introductory material.  http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html

Comment: Basil: that's a good article but it's written for people who already know how to write a makefile, discussing the pros and cons of specific styles of makefile.  I don't think it's a good text to explain makefiles to anyone.

Comment: I recommend outputting the compiled object files into a common directory that is separate from the source file directories. The link step(s) would use this common object directory. For the source files, include the relative paths in the make file dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This may take a few iterations. **You must start with the small and simple, and work up to the large and complex.**

First, create `bin/` yourself.

Now write a makefile that can build *one* object file:

```
bin/DisqueRango.o: src/DisqueRango.cpp
    g++ -c src/DisqueRango.cpp -o bin/DisqueRango.o
```

Get that working, and understand *how* it works, post a comment to tell us the result, and we'll proceed.

**EDIT:**

src/clients/makefile:

```
CC := g++

OBJ = *.cpp

all: prog

prog:
    $(CC) -c $(OBJ)
```

This makefile is effective but crude. It will rebuild all objects every time it is run, even if they are already up to date. We could add another command, `mv *.o ../../bin`, which would put them all into `bin/`, but I think it is better to improve the basic structure now, while the `clients` codebase is still simple.

The statement `OBJ = *.cpp` gives the variable `OBJ` the value `*.cpp`; the wildcard will not be expanded until the variable is used in the shell command. To assign a list of files to the variable, we use the [`wildcard`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function) function. To transform a list of source files (`foo.cpp`) into a list of object files (`foo.o`), we use the [`patsubst`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) function. To build the object files we use a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules), and within that rule we use [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) to refer to the source file (`foo.cpp`) and the target (`foo.o`).

```
CC := g++

SRC := $(wildcard *.cpp)             # foo.cpp bar.cpp baz.cpp
OBJ := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRC))  # foo.o bar.o baz.o

all: $(OBJ)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

Test that much to verify that it works. Now to have this makefile put the object files in `bin/`, we make a small change:

```
CC := g++
BIN := ../../bin


SRC := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ := $(patsubst %.cpp,$(BIN)/%.o,$(SRC))

all: $(OBJ)

$(BIN)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

**Verify that that much works,** and we'll move on to `src/disquerango/makefile`.

Comment: I did something that can generate .o files and link them all, using a feel makefiles, one in each folder.

for dir in $(OBJS); do (cd $$dir; ${MAKE} all); done 
did it for me

but i coudn't cread bin folder and put all .o inside. 
Would I be cheating if I use shell commands to do this? heh

Comment: Multiple makefiles are *sometimes* a good solution (I do not subscribe to "Recursive Make Considered Harmful"). If you are sure that you want to take this approach, then edit your question to include one of the makefiles (e.g. `src/clients/makefile`) and we'll modify it to put the object files in `bin/`.